# Return reference to object in DLL

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, dllexport

Hi fellow programmers.

I'm having a weird problem and have absolutely no clue of what's going on.

So I'm making a small library with some base things like maths and a window class.

Now to the problem, in my vec2 class I want to return a reference to a object but I get this compile error "error C2059: syntax error: '__declspec(dllexport)'"

```
class vec2 {
public:
float x, y;

vec2(float x = 0, float y = 0) : x(x), y(y) { }

float FW_API length();
vec2  FW_API normalize();
float FW_API dot(vec2& v);

vec2& FW_API rotate(float angle);
vec2& FW_API translate(float x, float y);
vec2& FW_API translate(vec2& v);

vec2 FW_API operator+(vec2& v);
vec2 FW_API operator-(vec2& v);
vec2 FW_API operator*(vec2& v);
vec2 FW_API operator/(vec2& v);
void FW_API operator+=(vec2& v);
void FW_API operator-=(vec2& v);
void FW_API operator*=(vec2& v);
void FW_API operator/=(vec2& v);

};
```

`FW_API` is defined to `__declspec(dllexport)`.

If I remove the ampersands it compiles without issue, but not with them.

So is it even possible to do that when exporting the methods to a dll?

Comment: Present your [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You normally export classes, not single functions of a class. Create a DLL project to get examples. BTW: Get a good book on C++ and read the chapter about "const correctness".

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thank you I got it to work :)

Comment: You should type up the solution as an answer of its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

class FW_API vec2

Putting the __declspec(dllexport) on the entire class instead of individual methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the "&" needs to go on the other side of the `declspec`:

Instead of:

```
vec2& FW_API rotate(float angle);
```

It should be:

```
vec2 FW_API & rotate(float angle);
```